# How to ngSwitchCase in ngFor?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularjs-ng-switch

From example in my code.

```ts
tabs: object = [
  { key: 'tab1', value: 'tab1' },
  { key: 'tab2', value: 'tab2' },
  { key: 'tab3', value: 'tab3' },
];
```

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="my_tab">
  <div *ngFor="let tab of tabs" *ngSwitchCase="'{{ tab.key }}'">
    {{ tab.value }}
  </div>
</div>
```

I always get an error with this code. How to do this?

Comment: How to do *what?* What is the expected output? You can't put two structural directives on the same element - perhaps you want an `ng-container` somewhere but it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Also note it's helpful to actually *include the error*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't put two structural directives on the same HTML tag. If you want your switch condition to be applied to each of the `ngFor` loop, you should write your HTML code like this:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="my_tab">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="tab.key">
      {{ tab.value }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Also the [`ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) allows to add a structural condition without interfering with the page's CSS style.

Comment: Doing it in this manner, the `div` with the ngFor still gets rendered. Is there any way to prevent the ngFor div from rendering?

Comment: @Kiong Maybe try to use an additional `<ng-container>` in place of the `<div>` used to loop with `ngFor`? (Downvoting other's answers in an attempt to promote your own answer is not very sportsmanship...)

Comment: Agreed that downvoting other's answer in an attempt to promote my own answer isn't very sportsmanship. However, I downvoted this answer because it doesn't really solve the issue (the `div` with the ngFor still gets rendered). I didn't downvote to promote my answer. My answer was provided quite a long time after I downvoted & commented.

Comment: @Kiong 7 minutes is not "quite a long time" according to me. Comment is posted at 17:04 yesterday and answer at 17:11 (just the time to write it). Also, downvote landed around the same span of time according to my reputation log.

Comment: You are right. Its my mistake. Very sorry for that. If you can modify your answer and I can remove the downvote, that'd be great :)

Comment: @Kiong I edited to try to avoid the empty div issue of the for loop. I couldn't test my answer since I don't have any Angular environment set up. If you can try this, I'd be curious to know if that solves the problem you mentioned. Thank you for raising that concern.